# Json serialization of html string

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

In Razor View  i have line like this:

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(new { tag = "<br />" }));
```

it raplaces html tags and generates response:

```
{"tag":"\u003cbr /\u003e"};
```

but i want it to return this:

```
{ tag = "<br />" }
```

what's the easiest way to do it?

Comment: { tag = "&lt;br /&gt;" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ugly but works.

```
    @{
        var json = Json.Encode(new {tag = "<br />"});
        var unicodeUnescaped = Regex.Replace(json,
           @"\\[Uu]([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})",
           m => char.ToString(
             (char)ushort.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)));
    }
    <p>@Html.Raw(unicodeUnescaped);</p>
```

Comment: But honestly, if that was the best I had I'd keep looking.